# React js components render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I'm starting in react for now and I'm a little confused, I'm using routes / private routes, and so I created a components folder where I will have my login components and my login / index.js folder where I import this component, but I'm No doubt what better way to do this:

my app.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import Routes from './routes';

function App() {
  return (
          <Routes/>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my routes js:

```
export default function Routes(){
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component = {Login}/> //só chama rota se o caminho for exato; 
                <PrivateRoute path="/home" component = {DashBoard}/>              
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

my component / LoginForm:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class LoginForm extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            login:'',
            password:'',
            errors: {},
            isLoading: false
        };
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    onChange(e){
        this.state({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    }

  render() {
    const { errors, login, password, isLoading } = this.state;
    return (
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
            <label for="login">Login</label>
            <input type="text" id="login" value={login} error= {errors.login} onChange={this.onChange} placeholder="Informe seu login" />
            <label for="password">Senha</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" value={password} error= {errors.password} onChange={this.onChange}   placeholder="Informe sua senha"/>
        <button className="btnEnt" type="submit" disabled ={isLoading}>Entrar</button>
    </form>
    )
  }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

Now i'm in doubt as i will call my login comp in my index.js file from my login page

index.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import loginComp from '../../components/LoginForm';


class Login extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
          <loginComp />
      )
    }
  }

  export default Login;
```

I don't have an error, but it doesn't render anything on screen

Comment: <loginComp/> if it is a component you have created in LoginForm then while importing do like this: import {loginComp} from "../../Components/LoginForm" this is called destructuring

Comment: import LoginPage from "../Components/pageName" and use <LoginPage /> in place of <loginComp/> this will solve your prblm

Comment: @Ayushi Keshiri 
What do you mean I didn't understand could you answer? For me to vote up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since, `<loginComp/>` is not a component you have created in LoginPage it is not rendering the data. You can simply change the

```
   import loginComp from '../../components/LoginForm';

to  import LoginForm from '../../components/LoginForm';
```

remember /components/LoginForm this is the file name you have saved and not the component you have created.

```
 render() {
      return (
          <LoginForm/>
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo right here:
`<ionChange}   placeholder="Informe sua senha"/>` and you repasted the bottom portion of the code.

Assuming this was a mistake and successfully compiles, you're only going to want that bottom `export default` and make sure your pathing is correct to that file.

Comment: Hi I did not undestand

Comment: Você colou o código incorretamente. Nevermind, Thanks Josh

Answer (score 0):

`./pages/login` does not exist, I believe you have named your login file `LoginForm`

Also, I am pretty sure . you need a div inside BrowserRouter, like so:

```
export default function Routes(){
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Login}/> 
                <PrivateRoute path="/home" component={DashBoard}/>              
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hello I edited the post was missing, stopped the error but is not rendering anything in the window

Comment: Updated my answer with a possible error in your router component.

Comment: I put it on, but to no avail I used a console.log in my /pages/login/index.js
and he appeared
he just isn't rendering mine:
          <loginComp />

Comment: import loginComp from '../../components/LoginForm';

Comment: try changing `onSubmit={this.onSubmit}` to `onSubmit={() => this.onSubmit}` and all your `onChange={this.onChange}` to `onChange={() => this.onChange}`

Comment: Also, in your router its `<Route path="/" exact component = {Login}/>` . but itshould be `<Route path="/" exact component={Login}/>`

Comment: It also didn't work out I had the exact, I think I went wrong with components / login form or
in pages / login / index